# Fouls by the goalkeeper when in possession of the ball

Tags: rules, football, officiating, goalkeeper

Is the ball considered to be in play or out of play when the goalkeeper has possession? What should be the restart if the goalkeeper commits a foul/misconduct when he has the ball in his hands?

Answer (score 1):

The goalkeeper having the ball is just like any other player having it. The ball is in play.

[The Laws](https://theifab.com/laws/latest/the-ball-in-and-out-of-play/) clearly state when the ball is out of play:

> The ball is out of play when:
>
> - it has wholly passed over the goal line or touchline on the ground or
>   in the air
> - play has been stopped by the referee
> - it touches a match official, remains on the field of play and:
>
>   - a team starts a promising attack or
>   - the ball goes directly into the goal or
>   - the team in possession of the ball changes

and

> The ball is in play at all other times when it touches a match
> official and when it rebounds off a goalpost, crossbar or corner
> flagpost and remains on the field of play.

If the goalkeeper commits a foul while holding the ball it's treated like any other foul. Depending on the offence it would likely result in a penalty or indirect freekick.